# Perl - Use all modules from specified subdirectory and solve it's dependencies automatically

Tags: perl, module, automation, exporter

I have two modules:

```
./My/Module1
./My/Module2
```

`Module1` is using subroutines from `Module2`. So in my script i typed following:

```
use My::Module1
use My::Module2
```

But this does not worked and perl complained that subroutines which are used from `Module2` by `Module1` does not exists. So I added following line to `Module1`:

```
use My::Module2
```

Finally this worked as expected.

I am wondering if there is some solution that will include all modules from specified sub-directory tree and solve dependencies automatically. I do not want to type `use` keyword in modules which depends on another modules. Following commands was tried but it did not worked (either by syntax errors or it used wrong modules):

```
use My::;
use My::*;
use My;
```

Also I would ask if this cross-using modules and calling it's subroutines is considered as a good practice in perl programming?

PS: `@INC` contains current directory so loading modules is working.

PPS: Modules used `Exporter`

Comment: "Also I would ask if this cross-using modules and calling it's subroutines is considered as a good practice in perl programming?" ... yes, as long as it's one-way, e.g. Module1 only requiring Module2. When you have Module1 rely on Module2 __and__ Module2 rely on Module1 you run into a dependency which you can't solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to type `use` keyword in modules which depends on another modules.

Then type the `BEGIN`, `require`, and `import` keywords instead?

Seriously, there's no good way for this to work. Just use `use` in each module so that it can load the things it needs.

> Also I would ask if this cross-using modules and calling it's subroutines is considered as a good practice in perl programming?

Yes. Modularization is considered good practice in **all** programming.