# Perl - nest modules and access subroutines from 2nd level nested modules in main script

Tags: perl, module

Is possible in perl to nest modules and export all nested subroutines to script which uses parent module? Consider following example:

Main script will use subroutines from ParentModule. So in script will be following line:

```
use ParentModule;
```

`ParentModule` will use subroutines from `ChildModule`. So in `ParentModule` will be following line:

```
use ChildModule;
```

Will subroutines exported under `ChildModule` available under main script?

Some times ago I've asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908530/perl-use-all-modules-from-specified-subdirectory-and-solve-its-dependencies-a) and answer was no, but this is quiet different than it was meant before. Also I have tried the scenario described above and it did not worked. Is there any another way how to do it?

PS: All modules uses exporter.

Thank you

Comment: If you switch the words "parent" and "child", what you're describing is [inheritance](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Inheritance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ParentModule` will need to explicitly provide the `ChildModule` symbols for export.  Since you are using `Exporter`, the easiest way to do that is:

In `ChildModule.pm`:

```
package ChildModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';

our @EXPORT = ( 'cf' );

sub cf { print "Child\n" }

1;
```

In `ParentModule.pm`:

```
package ParentModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';

use ChildModule;

our @EXPORT = ( 'pf', @ChildModule::EXPORT );

sub pf { print "Parent\n" }

1;
```

Then,

```
% perl -MParentModule -e 'pf; cf'
Parent
Child
```

It's not typically good form to export things by default, though.  You can play the same tricks with `@EXPORT_OK`, but you will still need to explicitly import the `ChildModule` routines into `ParentModule` or `ParentModule` won't be able to export them.

There are other modules which allow you to avoid that last step (e.g. [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into)) but you'll need to craft a custom `import()` routine in `ParentModule` if you want to retain the simple `use ParentModule` statement.